# Ionic - Some functionnalities are not working while compiling on IOS

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework

**Context:**

Hello, I am working on a Ionic application (made in Typescript). In this application, I control a wifi camera via HTTP Request to the IP (`http://192.72.1.1/myCommand` to be precise).

Main actions I do with the camera:

- Start recording
- Stop recording
- Get videos list
- Download a video

**When I use the Ionic DevApp:**

With the Ionic DevApp, everything works perfectly, I can do all mains actions without a problem.

**When I compile the application on IOS:**

I compile with the command `ionic cordova build ios --prod`, then I archive with Xcode and send it to the AppStore to test it with Test Flight.

I got no errors while compiling / archive the application. But when I try it on my iPhone, I can start / stop recording, but can't download the video.

**Problem:**

Some commands are not working, but I don't know if it is getting the list or downloading the video, I have no logs. I don't understand why some commands are working but others no.

IOS is blocking download requests? How to solve my problem?

**Notes:**

- I already tried all basic things like delete the IOS platform, recompile, uninstall, ...
- I tried different Ionic HTTP plugins, same problem with all of them.

**Some code:**

Start / Stop the camera: (it is the same command to start / stop).

```
  startCamera(){
      var url = "http://192.72.1.1/changeRecordStatus";
      var result = this.http.get(url);
      result.subscribe(data => {
          console.log("Works");
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error" + err);
        }
      );
  }
```

Getting the name of the last video:

```
    getLastVideo(){ 
    var url = "http://192.72.1.1/listVideos";
    this.http.get(url, {}, {})
    .then(data => {
      var xml = data.data
      var xmlDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
      var temp = this.xmlToJson(xmlDOM); // function that convert XML to JSON
      var resultArray = Object.keys(temp).map(function(i){
        let ite = temp[i];
        return ite;
      });
      resultArray = resultArray[0]['file'].reverse();
      this.lastVideo = resultArray[0]['name']; // lastVideo is a global variable
    },
    (error) =>{
      console.log("Error while getting the name of the last video" + error);
    });
  }
```

Downloading the file from the camera:

```
downloadFileFromCamera() {
      this.getLastVideo();
      var basename_file = this.lastVideo;
      var url = "http://192.72.1.1" + basename_file;
      this.fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(url), this.file.dataDirectory + '/videos/' +  basename_file, true).then((entry) => {
          this.video[this.counterVideos] = entry; // video is a global array
          this.counterVideos +=1;
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Error while downloading the last video" + error);
        });

  }
```

If someone knows how to solve my problem, I would be so grateful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ionic version are we talking about? Generally you can monitor your iPhone with a Mac and maybe get some more information about the error. If you have no access to a Mac, you can try to dig a little bit deeper by using the Ionic Pro plugin and monitoring service: https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/monitoring/#manual-capture-using-the-monitoring-api